# How to filter OSM data for addr keys with Osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, import, mysql, osmosis, osmfilter

I'm trying to import the address data of a specific country from an OSM file into a MySQL DB.

I tried to insert the data with osmosis and also to filter them with osmfilter before running OSM but without success.

After a long time of google search and frustration, I decided to post here my problem.

Can someone tell me how I can use the osmosis to import only data with following keys ->

```
'addr:city', 'addr:housenumber', 'addr:postcode', 'addr:street', 'addr:country', 'addr:housename', 'address',  'addr:place', 'addr:suburb', 'addr:province', 'addr:state', 'addr:number'
```

Comment: So the mysql part works, but the filtering is not effective, in that you get more data than you want?

Comment: Hey Billy, were you ever successfull at this?

Answer (score 2):

As stated here [link to previous article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125242/import-openstreetmap-data-osm-file-to-a-mysql-database-sql-file) while it is possible to add the data to MySQL common wisdom advises against this practice. Most of the tools have been developed to import OSM data in PostgresQL + PostGIS databases, for RDBMS or using GDAL toolkit, to convert OSM XML data to SpatiaLite file database.

Comment: that is not the problem. For MySQL exists already some tools like osmosis. my question is how can i extract only street data with help of osmosis or osmfilter?

Answer (score 2):

Osmosis has option for tag filter. here is the documentation. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.46#--tag-filter_.28--tf.29

```
Example usage:
osmosis \
  --read-xml input.osm \
  --tf accept-ways 'addr:city'=* \ 
  --tf accept-ways 'addr:housenumber'=* \
  ....
  --tf accept-ways 'addr:number'=* \
  --used-node \
  --write-xml output.osm
```